# Logging as User Without Password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

I have a `rails`, `mongoDB` app on Heroku. I need to troubleshoot for a user, but don't want to reset their password. Is there a way I can set my session to be logged in as that user, either from command line or decrypting the `md5` password?

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: Yeah, all users are through devise. I need to get to the front end, logged in as the user.

Comment: I would change their password. Then once you're done, copy and paste their old md5 password back to the db.

Comment: @AndrewWei that's a good idea,obviously dont send email notification of password change or reset.

Comment: Maybe think about using this feature of devise for the future - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin